# How to uncomment spyder python

Tags: python, comments, spyder

I have a block of code in the spyder ide for python.

```
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
```

Highlighting the chunk of code and then pressing ctrl - 4 comments it out

```
#print('hello world')
#print('hello world')
#print('hello world')
#print('hello world')
#print('hello world')
#print('hello world')
#print('hello world')
```

Uncommenting ONLY works some of the time by highlighting the code again and pressing crtl - 5. I want to return to my original chunk of code without comments.

```
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
print('hello world')
```

Anyone else had this problem with spyder?

Comment: which version of Spyder do you use? (the feature works fine for me, Spyder 4.0.0b7 on Windows 10)

Comment: and by the way, what you ask can also be achieved by selecting the block of code you'd like to (un)comment and pressing CTRL+1 - did you try that instead?

Answer (score 1):

try Ctrl + 1 (press simultaneously )
This won't take you entirely to where you started, but it's worth it..